Variance Chart in Highcharts
How would you create a Variance Chart using Highcharts?

I have successfully created an areaspline chart in Highcharts that has a uniform threshold using plotOptions.zones. If a value exceeds the threshold (100) then the area above the threshold is colored green. If the value falls below the threshold, then the area below, between the value and the threshold, is colored red.
const series = ...;
const categories = ...;
const plotOptions = {
  series: {
    threshold: 100,
    zones: [
      {
        value: 100,
        color: 'red'
      },{
        color: 'green'
      }
    ],
    marker: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: 'blue'
    }
  }
};
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    plotOptions: plotOptions,
    series: series
});

Single Threshold Fiddle

However, I need to create a "Variance Chart" in which the threshold can change from point to point along the x-axis. I have tried the following code to generate zones for the plotOptions, but it doesn't generate what I need. (I believe zones are supposed to be defined in the order that their value for the threshold increases.) How can I accomplish thie by configuring the Highcharts API, or would I need to create an extension?
const data = [
  { value: 29.9, threshold: 50 },
  { value: 71.5, threshold: 60 },
  { value: 106.4, threshold: 70 },
  { value: 129.2, threshold: 80 },
  { value: 144.0, threshold: 90 },
  { value: 176.0, threshold: 100 },
  { value: 135.6, threshold: 110 },
  { value: 148.5, threshold: 120 },
  { value: 216.4, threshold: 130 },
  { value: 194.1, threshold: 140 },
  { value: 95.6, threshold: 150 },
  { value: 54.4, threshold: 160 }
];
const series = [{
  data: data.map(obj => obj.value)
}];
const plotOptions = createPlotOptions(data);
// Update the thresholds dynamically
function createPlotOptions(data) {
  return {
    areaspline: {
      zones: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          value: d.threshold,
          color: (d.value < d.threshold) ? 'red' : 'green'
        };
      })
    }
  };
}
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    plotOptions: plotOptions,
    series: series
});


Could you please share an image of what the chart should look like? Please also provide the data for the chart from the image. It'll be easier for me to help you!

@DominikChudy The first image is an example of what a chart would look like. If you would like some sample data, then you can use the 'data' variable provided in the second example. It has both 'value' and 'threshold' for each data point. (To be clear the data given does not match the example chart)

I'm afraid that it'll be hard to get this effect through the API options. Zones probably won't work here. I was thinking about creating a seperate series for each point to be able to color the area beneath it correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/86eu0ty3/ Still it needs some improvements.

@DominikChudy Thanks for trying. I've come up with a solution that I believe will work, which I will include as an answer.

I came up with a solution using a stacked spline chart by creating a transparent 'base' series to offset the values from the goals (thresholds) versus the 'actual' measured values for each point in the series.
let data = [
  { value: 70, threshold: 50 },
  { value: 71.5, threshold: 30 },
  { value: 50, threshold: 70 },
  { value: 129.2, threshold: 80 },
  { value: 95, threshold: 90 },
  { value: 120, threshold: 70 },
  { value: 115, threshold: 90 },
  { value: 80, threshold: 115 },
  { value: 180, threshold: 65 },
  { value: 150, threshold: 80 },
  { value: 95.6, threshold: 110 },
  { value: 54.4, threshold: 100 }
];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let obj = data[i];
  if (obj.value > obj.threshold) {
    obj.above = obj.value - obj.threshold;
    obj.below = 0;
    obj.base = obj.threshold;
  } else {
    obj.above = 0
    obj.below = obj.threshold - obj.value;
    // offset the base below the measured value
    obj.base = obj.value - (obj.threshold - obj.value);
  }
  data[i] = obj;
}

const series = [
{
  name: 'Above',
  type: 'areaspline',
  data: data.map(obj => obj.above),
  linkedTo: 'actual',
  color: 'rgba(0,128,0,1)'  
},
{
  name: 'Below',
  type: 'areaspline',
  data: data.map(obj => obj.below),
  linkedTo: 'actual',
  color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)'  
},
{
  name: 'Base',
  type: 'areaspline',
  data: data.map(obj => obj.base),
  linkedTo: 'actual',
  fillOpacity: 0,
},
{
  name: 'Actual',
  id: 'actual',
  type: 'spline',
  lineWidth: 2,
  zIndex: 1,
  color: 'yellow',
  data: data.map(obj => obj.value)
},
{
  name: 'Goal',
  id: 'goal',
  type: 'spline',
  dashStyle: 'longdash',
  zIndex: 2,
  data: data.map(obj => obj.threshold)
}];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Variance Chart'
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      formatter: function() {
        // Only include Actual and Goal series in the shared tooltip.
        const points = this.points.filter(point => {
          return point.series.name === 'Actual' || point.series.name === 'Goal';
        });

        let tooltipHtml = `<b>${this.x}</b><br/>`;
        points.forEach(point => {
          tooltipHtml += `<span style="color:${point.color}">\u25CF</span> ${point.series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b><br/>`;
        });

        return tooltipHtml;
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        marker: {
          enabled: true
        },
        showInLegend: true
      },
      areaspline: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        showInLegend: false
      }
    },
    series: series
});

A link to the fiddle.
Here's what it looks like:


Nice, it's looking very good. Thanks for sharing!
